# How to superimpose two UIViews in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, storyboard

I have two views, ViewA and ViewB. How do I superimpose ViewB over ViewA? In my case ViewA is a TableView where the custom cells are UIImageViews. And ViewB is a UIView with two small (in heigh) children: a UILabel and a UIImageView. I need ViewB to always be on top so as user swipes/scroll the cells of ViewA, ViewB is always there in the foreground. Is there a way to do this in the storyboard? So far I can only superimpose the content (i.e. ImageView) of the TableViewCell with ViewB so that ViewB would itself belong to the Cell. But what I want is to superimpose ViewB over the entire TableView.

Answer (score 0):

just drag to the ViewB after the ViewA.

This example, the label is at the top of the button.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101235685/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-23%20at%201.30.19%20PM.png